# Flushed cat litter, maybe clogged?

Tags: plumbing

I stupidly flushed some cat litter a couple times yesterday( 2-3 flushes so i didnt do it all at once and clog it). I now realize i should not have done this as it causes major problems. Im in an apartment.

The toilet seems to be flushing and filling back up fine, but once the bowl fills back up with water and once it stops running i notice the water recedes about 2 inches or so. I even noticed when the neighbor flushed there toilet more got sucked out of mine a bit. I am assuming it is just cloged and thats what i need to fix?

Any tips or suggestions or has this happened to someone else?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Knowing what other fixtures are on the same drain (toilets, showers and sinks, above and below) would help us guess as to your difficulty.

Comment: Unfortunately, i do not know the answer to this question as i am house sitting for someone. Can you give me an answer to all?

Answer (score 1):

The litter has probably gathered in the piping underneath the toilet in the closet bend. You might try forcing a water hose down through the toilet until it stops. Make sure you get all the way through the toilet and near the closet bend. The more pressure you can get, the better. Run the water at high pressure for a considerable period of time to wash the clay as far down as possible. That might help prevent more issues down the plumbing line. ***If you know anyone that has the skills, remove the toilet first and see if you might be able to use a shop vac and suck out as much of the clay as possible.***

Chemical drain openers will not dissolve clay. Don't waste your money.

[image: Closet Bend]

Answer (score -2):

Well first off don’t ever do that again. Cat litter carries heavy volume like material. There’s a reason why people use cat litter to clean oil spills. However it sounds like you’ll be ok. Your toilet and neighbors toilet are probably different toilets. As in one has a more powerful flush than the other. However it won’t hurt to get something like rid x (if you have a septic tank) or drano will help.